# Failed to update a map with assoc in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have following map in my Clojure code:

```
typeList {"int"  {"type"    ["integer"]
                         "minimum" -2147483648
                         "maximum" 2147483647}
                 "bigint" {"type"    ["integer"]
                           "minimum" -9223372036854775808
                           "maximum" 9223372036854775807}}
```

I am trying to add some new values to that map and I am using `assoc` key for that; however it seems it is not adding the new value since the `println` is not giving the new keyword.

For example, let's add "asd" to the map:

```
(assoc typeList "asd" {"type"    ["integer"]})
```

However, when I try to print the new list, it returns as following:

```
(println typeList)
```

> {int {type [integer], minimum -2147483648, maximum 2147483647}, bigint
> {type [integer], minimum -9223372036854775808, maximum
> 9223372036854775807}}

Am I missing something? Couldn't figure that out since I am newbie in Clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`assoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) *will not change the existing value* `typeList`, instead it *returns a new value* with the key `"asd"`. In other words, `typeList` will be *unchanged* and the return value from `assoc` will contain the `"asd"` key.

Try this instead:

```
(def updatedTypeList (assoc typeList "asd" {"type"    ["integer"]}))

(get typeList "asd")
;; => nil

(get updatedTypeList "asd")
;; => {"type" ["integer"]}
```

Comment: Thanks. But let's say I need to add n values, should I do same operation at each time?

Comment: @stuck You could use `into` for that.